# How do I total the values in a 2D ArrayList object?

Tags: java

Here is my attempt at creating a 2D ArrayList object of integers.
The constructor, fillArray, and displayArray methods seem to work (aside from displaying brackets around each of my integers, which I don't understand).

The problem is that I don't know how to work with the values that I filled into the 2D ArrayList object for summing.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class TwoDArray
{
    // fields
    private ArrayList<Integer>[][] myList;
    private int listSize;

    // methods
    /**
     * The constructor creates a 2D ArrayList object.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public TwoDArray(int size)
    {
        listSize = size;
        myList = new ArrayList[size][size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                myList[i][j] = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);
    }

    /**
     * The fillArray method fills the 2D ArrayList object
     * with randomly generated numbers between 0 and 99.
     */
    public void fillArray()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < listSize; j++)
            {
                myList[i][j].add(rand.nextInt(100));
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * The displayArray method displays the 2D
     * ArrayList object.
     */
    public void displayArray()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < listSize; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(myList[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    /**
     * The getTotal method sums the values in the
     * 2D ArrayList object.
     * @return The sum of the values.
     */
    public int getTotal()
    {
        int total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < listSize; j++)
                total += myList[i][j].get(j); // don't know what to do here

        return total;
    }
```

Comment: Think about accept/vote up the answer also ;)

Comment: @Ryan Hallberg I am afraid you misunderstood how arrayList works. list[][] with each list holding 1 element does not give you dynamicity, neither will you be granted the ability to change its size. It will work just like a normal 2D array. If you want a fully dynamic matrix, that will be an arraylist of arraylist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create an array of`ArrayList`, and you give to these `ArrayList` only *ONE* value, so to sum all of them you only need to get the first value from each :

```
for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < listSize; j++)
        total += myList[i][j].get(0);
```

If you try like `get(1)` you'll get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because it does not exists

---

*Next to that*, you create `ArrayList`, and store only *ONE* element so may only use a `int[][]`.

But if you need to store multiple values in each box, like adding them like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < listSize; j++){
        myList[i][j].add(rand.nextInt(100));
        myList[i][j].add(rand.nextInt(100));
        myList[i][j].add(rand.nextInt(100));
    }
}
// In each box you'll have a List, containing 3 values
```

To get the sum of ALL int you may do :

```
for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < listSize; j++)
        total += myList[i][j].stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```

This will sum all the element of each box

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked. Could you explain what the logic is behind this?

Comment: @RyanHallberg I've edited, but a question : why are an array of List which contain only 1 element ? very useless compare to a simple ``int[][]

Comment: I am new to Java. But the idea behind using 2D ArrayList was to have the size dynamic, as in, it would accommodate a user specified size.

Comment: @RyanHallberg and what is the goal ? because once the array is created its size is not dynamic, only the element in each bocx not very usefull

Comment: @RyanHallberg That would be represented as `List<List<Integer>>`, not `ArrayList[][]` (which would technically be a 3d array). With the code you've shown, the only way to set the size is via the constructor, which is currently used to size the array (not the list). Don't see why you aren't using an `int[][]`.

Comment: @Vince Emigh, I see. I'm working through some textbook problems trying to familiarize myself with Java syntax. Admittedly, my use of ArrayList object for this problem may be inappropriate.